# Is this map an open map or not?

Tags: functional-analysis

$X$ is a normed linear space, $ S=$ ${x:\|x\|=1} $ is the unit sphere of $X$.

A map $ f:X\setminus \{0\}\to S $ is given by $ f(x) = x/\|x\| $.

The question is:  the map $ f : X\setminus \{0\}\to S$ is forever an open map, whatever $\dim X$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cone}{\operatorname{Cone}}$Let $U \subset X\setminus \{0\}$ be an open set, and consider $\Cone(U) = \{x\neq 0: cx \in U$ for some $c >0\}$. Note that 
$$\Cone(U) = \bigcup_{c>0}\ cU$$
is open. Thus $\Cone(U)\cap S$ is open in $S$. Hence $f$ is open as $f(U) = \Cone(U) \cap S$.

Comment: Well, two answers are all right...By the way, cone(u) is consitent with the cone of geometry or algebra or topology?

Comment: It is something more geometrical then topological: In topology one can always form a cone of a topological space. In that case the vertex is always included (in our case it is not). @DavidChan

Answer (score 0):

Note that $U$ is open in  $S$ **iff** $U = V\cap S$ where $V$ is open in $X$.

I claim that $B({x \over \|x\|}, {\epsilon \over \|x\|}) \cap S \subset f(B(x,\epsilon))$, which would imply that $f$ is an open map.

Note that  $f(x) = f(\lambda x)$ for all $\lambda \neq 0$.

Suppose $y \in B({x \over \|x\|}, {\epsilon \over \|x\|}) \cap S$, then
$\|y - {x \over \|x\|} \| < { \epsilon \over \|x\|}$ and so $\|x\|y \in B(x,\epsilon)$. Since $f(\|x\|y) = f(y) = y$ (because $y \in S$), we see that
$y \in f(B(x,\epsilon))$.